# Dynamic “Back To Top” floating button, making it IE8 Compatible

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, compatibility

I'm using the following code http://www.developerdrive.com/2013/07/using-jquery-to-add-a-dynamic-back-to-top-floating-button-with-smooth-scroll/ and it works Awesome in Chrome and FF but I just get nothing in IE8.

I view the page in IE8 and the back to top text isn't even visible.

This is my rendered source code in IE8 of http://developerdrive.developerdrive.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/scroll-to-top.html

https://gist.github.com/YOUConsulting/7635669b05c16751d5d8

Kr,
Vince

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in this example - http://www.developerdrive.com/2013/07/using-jquery-to-add-a-dynamic-back-to-top-floating-button-with-smooth-scroll/  they use the newest Jquery version - jQuery 2.0, which leaves behind the older Internet Explorer 6, 7, and 8 browsers. 
try to use the old-ie compatible version:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js

and Ie8 doesn't support rgb colors here.

```
.back-to-top {background-color: rgba(235, 235, 235, 0.8);}
```

need to change for hex color hack for ie8 (without opacity)